# Set focus on InputText in Blazor without JS

Tags: c#, blazor

Could You tell me is there possible to set a focus on InputText in Blazor without JS using .Net 5?
Maybe I'm wrong, but fallowing the cases in the documentation i need a ref to an input (not InputText) before i set focus. But maybe there is a way to do that?
Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

The source code to the [Input Components](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms)

For example this how I inherited `InputText` and extended it to get a reference to the underlying input element: `builder.AddElementReferenceCapture(5, (__ref) => { Element = __ref; });`

```
public class FInputText : InputText, IFocusInput
{
    public ElementReference Element { get; set; }
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "input");
        builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", CssClass);
        builder.AddAttribute(3, "value", BindConverter.FormatValue(CurrentValue));
        builder.AddAttribute(4, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString));
        builder.AddElementReferenceCapture(5, (__ref) => { Element = __ref; });
        builder.CloseElement();
    }
}
```

Now that I have access to the element reference a simple extension to give me the same functionality as `FocusAsync()`.

```
public static class FocusExtensions
{
    public static ValueTask FocusAsync(this IFocusInput focusInput)
        => focusInput.Element.FocusAsync();
}
```

I created a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OrakTech.Inputs/) with 5 of them done.

Here is the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/BrianLParker/OrakTech.Inputs/tree/master/OrakTech.Inputs/Components) for the source.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 5 ,
you can use a **FocusAsync** method on **ElementReference** for the UI focus on that element.

```
<button @onclick="() => textInput.FocusAsync()">Set focus</button>
<input @ref="textInput"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this in .Net 6 to set focus to an InputText, don't see why it shouldn't work for .Net5.

```
@page "/ListCustomers"
@inherits ListCustomersBase

<EditForm Model="@model" >

    <InputText id="inputText" @ref="inputText" @bind-Value="model" />
    
    <button id="setFocus" @onclick="@buttonSetFocus_click">Set focus</button>

</EditForm>

@code{
    string model = "";
    InputText inputText;

    void buttonSetFocus_click(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(inputText.Element.HasValue == true ) // don't 
        {
            inputText.Element.Value.FocusAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: .net 5 `InputText` did not expose the element.